# When and where did "not" become commonly used in contraction for, as in "didn't"?

Tags: history, contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Were contractions less common in olden days?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8900/were-contractions-less-common-in-olden-days)

I have read some old books in which they did not use "didn't", "wasn't", or similar contractions with "not". I just watched the recent movie "True Grit" in which they also didn't use "didn't", etc. Were these contractions a recent or regional addition to the language?

Comment: The recent True Grit was a remake of a John Wayne True Grit from 1969.

Comment: The "exact duplicate" question refers to contractions in general, not "not". In that question, the only answer in reference to "not" contractions includes a dead link. A question closed as an exact duplicate should be answered in the duplicate. This one is not (isn't).

Comment: So? You're even asking *about the same movie*.

Comment: Read the first sentence. Even so, if every question in this site referred to a movie, it would not make those questions duplicates of one another.

Comment: Goodness. The fundamentals of the questions are exactly the same, ergo yours is a dupe.

Comment: Fundamentally, this question is about the contraction of "not." The "exact duplicate" is about contractions in general, which will necessarily provide a non-specific and, in this case, inadequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Barren Brainerd** published a paper - *The contractions of not: A historical note.” Journal of English Linguistics 22:176-196* in 1989, in which he noted that the contraction of not first appeared in writing in 1700s, increased in 1800s, and were more or less accepted in 1900s.

The actual paper which Brainerd published is not accessible, but [here](http://www.historicalconference.swspiz.pl/Book%20of%20abstracts.pdf) is the source which talks about it. Refer to page 26.

Answer (score 0):

The OED’s earliest citation for *don’t* under the entry for *do* is dated 1672 and for *didn’t*, 1775. The earliest citation for *won’t* under the entry for *will*  is 1710.