# "For who so firm that cannot be seduced?" Where is the verb in this Shakespeare quotation?

Tags: grammar, seventeenth-century-english

He says:

> ... Therefore it is meet
>   That noble minds keep ever with their likes,
>   *For who so firm that cannot be seduced?*
>   (*Julius Caesar*, Act 1, Scene 2)

Roughly means that you shouldn't pal around with bad guys, because they'll eventually seduce you into bad deeds.

Why is the verb in the italicized sentence omitted? Was/Is there an underlying rule to that?

Comment: I suggest that you read up on [metre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_%28poetry%29).

Comment: In terse epigrammatic and proverbial style, the verb-to-be (who **is** so firm that ...) is sometimes dropped.   **Who so deaf as he that will not hear.**.   There is a second ellipsis: ... so firm **that he** cannot be seduced.

Comment: @RegDwigнt. "Who's so firm" would have been equally metrical.

Comment: @fdb point taken. In which case, the answer is, "only Shakespeare knows, and he's been dead forever". Either version is grammatical, and he has to pick *something*, and so he did, and here it is.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Surely it means that the question needs reopening? Just because *we* don't know doesn't mean no-one else does.

Comment: @Araucaria I agree.  What kind of comment is go read metre?  The article is huge.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I think the question should be opened.

Comment: @TimRomano Thank you. I take it that in this kind of style you can generally leave out anything that could be guessed at. I was looking for more limitation on this generality, but Reg Dwigнt has, ever so kindly,  closed the question. Thank him too. I don't know what meter has to do with this, since meter is a rhythmic restriction, not a grammatical one.

Comment: Actually, I retract the point about the second ellipsis.  **That** is the relative pronoun. http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cpercy/courses/6362-lee.htm

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical in normal speech (needs the 'is') but this is poetry so anything goes as long as it sounds good (goes with the meter as others mentioned)

Answer (score 4):

It's not as common in modern usage, but especially in poetry, copulae ("is", "are") and subject pronouns ("he", "they") can be omitted when the context makes the meaning clear. The clause could also be written

> for who **is** so firm that **they** cannot be seduced?

But this doesn't fit into the meter. (Shakespeare liked iambic meters, i.e. lines of alternating unstressed-stressed syllables: "for *who* so *firm* that *can*not *be* se*duced*?")

Comment: If don't say it, then someone else will:  For who is so firm that *he* cannot be seduced?

Comment: Any guess as to why "who's" wasn't used?  Was "who's" used at that time, or is this more modern?

Comment: @michael_timofeev I believe contractions have become more common in writing within the last century or so. [This answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/8912/138581) has some more information.

Comment: @michael: it may actually be a mis-transcription for *"for who's so firm that cannot be seduced"*. They're pronounced almost (if not exactly) the same, and shortening *is* to *'s* was a contraction used by Shakespeare.

Comment: @Draconis As mentioned in one of the comments above,I think that in defining relative clauses **that** is a relative pronoun itself, and it's not necessary to call for a pronoun after it.

Comment: @Draconis Speaking of iambic meters, can I ask you if the verse before (That noble minds keep ever with their likes) is iambic? I'm new to poetry, so ...

Comment: @Farid It is indeed. Most of Shakespeare's dialogue is in iambic pentameter, which means five iambs (short-long patterns) per line. "That NOble MINDS keep EVer WITH their LIKES." (Comment formatting won't let me turn on italics mid-word so using caps this time.)

Comment: @PeterShor it is not a misprint.  I checked my first folio edition and the line is as quoted here.

Comment: @michael: and why do you think there weren't mistakes in the first folio? There most definitely [were](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crux_(literary)). For one famous example, I believe the consensus is that *"a table of green fields"* (in the first folio) should really be *"he babbled of green fields".*

Comment: @PeterShor there's a difference between mistakes, interpretations, or "helpful editing."  I'm not going to get drawn into a debate on First Folio criticism, or whether it should have been "who's".

Comment: @michael: I don't want a debate about this either. You asked for any guesses as to why it wasn't *who's*, and I pointed out that the contraction *who is→who's* was used by Shakespeare, and that one possibility was that it was simply a "typo".

Comment: @cobaltduck Why would you write that? The singular/indefinite *they* is much much much older than Shakespeare!

Comment: @curiousdannii:  Sigh.  I accept that the road I walk is a lonely one.  Ne'theless, I remain firmly entrenched within this camp, where we believe with all our being that "singular 'they' is evil."  However, should you wish to end any sentences with prepositions, my friend, then I say go right ahead.

Comment: @cobaltduck Evil it may be, but it's been an ordinary part of English since at least Chaucer!